# Derivation of the formula for ${ }_{n} P_{r}=\frac{n !}{(n-r) !}$ and ${ }_{n} C_{r}=\frac{n !}{r !(n-r) !}$

Tags: permutations, combinations

\begin{align}
&\sideset{_n}{_r}{P} =\frac{n !}{(n-r) !} \\
&\sideset{_n}{_r}{C}=\frac{n !}{r !(n-r) !}
\end{align}
Where ${ }_{n} P_{r}$ = permutation, ${ }_{n} C_{r}$ = number of combinations, $n$ =   total number of objects in the set, $r$  =   number of objects selected or number of choosing objects from the set

Comment: The combination formula comes from dividing out all the subsets that contain the same $r$ objects, of which there are $r!$ ways to select those objects. This accounts for the "order doesn't matter."

Answer (score 1):

The first formula is simply $n \times n-1 \times \cdots \times n-r+1$ which is correct by the fundamental counting principal. First you pick one of $n$, then you pick one of the remaining $n-1$, and so on.

The second formula is obtained by dividing the first formula by the number of distinct ways of choosing those $r$ terms, since we don't care about the order in which they are selected. The logic used in the first formula tells us this means we should divide by $r!$.